# How do I open a popup window in ASP.Net with HyperLink control using external javascript file?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, popup, hyperlink

Using ASP.Net 2.0

a. On a parent ASPX page, after a HyperLink control is clicked, I need to open a (child) page in a popup window, as modal.

b. Then when that popup window (child page) is closed, I need to get the selections from a datagrid on that popup window and refresh the parent page accordingly.

c. I have open window javascript code in a javascript.js file, which I am loading like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.GetType(), "manualequipentryscript", "javascript.js");
  lnkSearchProducts.Attributes.Add("onclick", "LaunchProductSearch();");
}
```

..isn't working..

How do I implement this?

( I searched the www for the past 2 hours and came up with so many results by haven't been able to get anything concrete that would help me. )

Regards,
Bob

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify why the code "isn't working". What error do you get ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Does it generate an error? If so, is it when the page is loaded or when the button is clicked? Please provide markup that is being sent to client.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to understand is that browsers generally do not allow true modal popup windows (with the notable exception of IE). Mozilla based browsers allow you to specify that a window will remain in front, but that cannot be considered modal. [This article](http://javascript.about.com/library/blmodal.htm) expands on this actuality.

The usual workaround is to display a Modal dialog in a DIV instead of another window.

Secondly, in order to pass values from a popup window to the parent window, you can either use Javascript methods or server side code. The former method would involve first accessing the parent window (using the `window.opener` property) and then retrieving references to elements within that parent window. See [this article](http://www.webreference.com/js/tutorial1/opener.html) for an example.

The server side method would require you to persist state values and then force a Javascript refresh of the parent window (using `window.opener.location.reload();`) to enable those values to be loaded.

Finally, the code you have presented seems about right to me. Tell us the error message you get... that may provide a clue.